# How to handle changes in composite type in postgreSQL

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, dapper, psql

I am about to learn postgresql and i ran in some kind of a problem. I want to have most of my connection from website to db through stored procedure(functions). I have about 20 functions so far where 5 of those functions returned exactly the same table with columns i.e:

```
create or replace function my_Function( t text )
returns setof table(uid uuid,testText text, randomInt int ...)
...
```

since table(uid uuid,testText text, randomInt int ...) repeated itself 5 times i figured out that i could use composite type to return the same type of data from my functions, so if i need to return an extra column i could just change my composite type and voila, all 5 functions should return same columns.

Unfortunately thats not how that works, as soon as i added a new column to my composite type all the functions which used my composite type broke with saem error:

```
Final statement returns too few columns
```

which makes sense because i dont select an extra column to fit the composite type.

Are there any way to tell which functions use a composite type as return type? 
Are there any way to force composite type to fill in blanks for newly created column (if not, then i can as well use the table(...) return type, because it dont solve the redundancy problem which i try to avoid)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example setup:

```
create type my_type as (id int, name text);

create or replace function my_function_1()
returns setof my_type language plpgsql as $$
declare
    rec my_type;
begin
    rec.id := 1;
    rec.name := 'name';
    return next rec;
end $$;

create or replace function my_function_2()
returns setof my_type language plpgsql as $$
begin
    return query select 1::int, 'name'::text;
end $$;
```

> Are there any way to tell which functions use a composite type as return type?

Yes:

```
select nspname as schema_name, proname as function_name
from pg_proc p
join pg_namespace n on n.oid = pronamespace
join pg_type t on t.oid = prorettype
where typname = 'my_type';

 schema_name | function_name 
-------------+---------------
 public      | my_function_1
 public      | my_function_2
(2 rows)
```

> Are there any way to force composite type to fill in blanks for newly created column?

No. You could try to recreate (without modifications) the functions after adding a new attribute to the type:

```
alter type my_type add attribute new_col int;
create or replace function my_function_1() ...
create or replace function my_function_2() ...
```

But only the functions which return next variable of the type will work properly (`my_function_1()` will work, `my_function_2()` won't).

Comment: Hmmm that's sounds constrictive. If it's that difficult to modify, I wouldn't go there.

Answer (score 0):

What advantage do you gain by using Postgres composite types? It seems like a world of pain. Can I explore how this would work with [QueryFirst](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbsimonbb.QueryFirst)? Your procedures would be in .sql files in your app, versioned with your app, source controlled. For the 5 procedures that share a return type, you would create a C# interface. In each of the 5 Results.cs files, on the results partial class, inherit the interface. As such, the 5 procs could evolve separately, adding columns as needed. If ever you modified a proc such that it no longer fulfilled the interface: compile errors. A much more forgiving, change-tolerant scenario.

disclaimer: I wrote QueryFirst